# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning on async await promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` on async await promise

I have this code:

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.foo.findOne({}, (err, docs) => {
      if (err || !docs) return reject();
      return resolve();
    });
  });
}

async function foobar() {
  await foo() ? console.log("Have foo") : console.log("Not have foo");
}

foobar();
```

Which results with:

> (node:14843) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): false
>
> (node:14843) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Note: I know I can solve this issue like this:

```
foo().then(() => {}).catch(() => {});
```

But then we are "back" to callbacks async style.

How do we solve this issue?

Comment: What's `db.foo`? Is it Mongoose?

Comment: @estus No, it's MongoJS, see here https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs

Comment: `try/catch` is necessary for `async/await`. If you want to write those codes with async/await style, you can try [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original), which deal with functions following the error-first callback style.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with `foo().catch(console.error)`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Wrap your code in `try-catch` block.

```
async function foobar() {
  try {
    await foo() ? console.log("Have foo") : console.log("Not have foo");
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('Catch an error: ', e)
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using the async await to reduce un-necessary code. Try and catch blocks are really not the goal in here - I could have just using the regular callbacks as mentioned above.

Comment: @Raz Error handling is not 'unnecessary'. Would you consider `try..catch` unnecessary in synchronous code? It's same thing for `async`.

Comment: @Raz `async/await` is syntactic sugar that allows you to write synchronous looking like code. How do you handle errors in sync code? --> `try/catch`. In first place it's not meant to reduce code at all (- even though it's ofthen the case)

Comment: @Raz, I hope you @estues and @Kristianmitk resolved your question. Moreover, node is only giving `warning`, if you don't care about error handling, then you can just ignore the warnings also, but I would highly suggest otherwise. Its just good practice to add proper handling for runtime errors.

Comment: Should async await be followed by a promise? Could I just remove the promise and return `true` or `false` in the foo function? I have tried and it does not working.

Comment: To use async operation you have to use either callback, promise or async/await. You cannot just return `true/false`.

Answer (score 6):

`then(() => {}).catch(() => {})` isn't needed because `catch` doesn't necessarily should go after `then`.

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` means that a promise weren't synchronously chained with `catch`, this resulted in unhandled rejection.

In `async..await`, errors should be caught with `try..catch`:

```
async function foobar() {
  try {
    await foo() ? console.log("Have foo") : console.log("Not have foo");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

The alternative is to handle errors at top level. If `foobar` is application entry point and isn't supposed to be chained anywhere else, it's:

```
foobar().catch(console.error);
```

The problem with `foo` is that it doesn't provide meaningful errors. It preferably should be:

```
if (err || !docs) return reject(err);
```

Also, most popular callback-based libraries have promise counterparts to avoid `new Promise`. It `mongoist` for `mongojs`.

Answer (score 3):

Every solution here just silences the error, but **you should probably handle the error** instead.

How you handle it depends on the error and on what part of the application you're in. Here are some examples.

### You're writing an app

If you're writing a node app and something throws, you might want to use `process.exit(1)` to quit the app and display the error to the user:

```js
async function init() {
  await doSomethingSerious();
}

init().catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1)
});
```

### You're writing a module

If the code **expects** an error, you can catch it and use it as a value instead:

```js
module.exports = async function doesPageExist(page) {
  try {
    await fetchPage(page);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.message === '404') {
      return false;
    }

    // Unrecognized error, throw it again
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Notice that this example re-throws the error when it's not the expected one. **This is fine**. It's the final user’s responsibility to handle network errors:

```js
const doesPageExist = require('my-wonderful-page-checker');

async function init() {
  if (await doesPageExist('https://example.com/nope')) {
    console.log('All good')
  } else {
    console.log('Page is missing ')
  }
}

// Just like before
init().catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1)
});
```

### You're the user

If you're seeing this error when using a prepackaged application via command line, like webpack or babel, it might mean that the application had an error but it was not handled. This depends on the application or your input is not correct. Refer to the application’s manual.