# Looking for help Error while making Music bot for discord using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, discord

Working on making a music bot for discord but this error keeps popping up.

> (node:2144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not found
> at C:\Users\Xy\Desktop\Dream Bot\node_modules\discord-player\src\Player.js:285:35
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:2144)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:2144) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.'

Any help is appreciated! Been stuck on this for hours following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBj_UlaG_Ig&list=LL&index=2&ab_channel=DashCruft

My code is

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const { Player } = require("discord-player");
const player = new Player(bot);
bot.player = player;

bot.login()

bot.on("ready", bot => {
    console.log('Bot is Online!')
})

bot.on("message", async message =>  {
    const prefix = '?';
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command ==='play') {
        let track = await bot.player.play(message.member.voice.channel, args[0], message.member.user.tag);
        message.channel.send('Currently playing ${track.name}! - Requested by ${track.requestedBy}');
    
    }
    
    if (command === 'stop') {
        let track = await bot.player.stop(message.guild.id);
    message.channel.send('STOPPED');
    }
})
```

Comment: have you installed `discord-player`

Comment: Well the error message seems to contain your problem if you read it `This error originated ... by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning on async await promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811197/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-on-async-await-promise)