# Async/await: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, socket.io

In my socket.io app, I'm trying to send an array of users in a room to the client in order to create a `ul` element showing all the users in the room. The [docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-instance/#fetchSockets) say that you can use the following code to return all socket instances in the given namespace and room:

```js
// return all Socket instances in the "room1" room of the "admin" namespace
const sockets = await io.of("/admin").in("room1").fetchSockets();
```

However, it involves `await`, which is something I'm not very experienced with. I just put the code block inside an `async` function, which I'm not sure is the best way of doing things.

```js
io.of('/game').on('connection', socket => {
    console.log(`Socket ID: ${socket.id}`);
    
    const cookies = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie || "");
    console.log(cookies);
    const currentUser = cookies['current_user'];
    const roomName = cookies['room_name'];

    socket.username = currentUser;

    console.log(`${socket.username} connected to room "${roomName}"`);
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`${socket.username} disconnected from room "${roomName}"`);
        io.of('/game').in(roomName).emit('leave', socket.username);
    });

    socket.join(roomName);

    (async() => {
        const usersInRoom = await io.of('/game').in(roomName).fetchSockets();
        console.log(`Number of users connected: ${usersInRoom.length}`);
        io.of('/game').in(roomName).emit('join', { username: socket.username, users: usersInRoom });
    })();
});
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error in the console:

```
(node:9872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:28:19)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9872) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've tried to do some research on this, and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52811260/9632440), which suggests wrapping the code in a `try-catch` block. I've done this:

```js
(async() => {
    try {
        const usersInRoom = await io.of('/game').in(roomName).fetchSockets();
        console.log(`Number of users connected: ${usersInRoom.length}`);
        io.of('/game').in(roomName).emit('join', { username: socket.username, users: usersInRoom });
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

but I still get an error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:28:19)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (<path>\node_modules\socket.io-parser\dist\is-binary.js:49:63)
```

How should I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May need to see surrounding code. Nothing there looks unordinary. It's funny that you actually got a 'stack overflow'.

Comment: @DanielDuong I've edited the question.

Comment: You can't send the variable `usersInRoom` over socket.io.  That is a list of actual socket.io data structures which are not something that can be converted to JSON to send over socket.io and even if it was able to be sent over socket.io, it wouldn't mean anything to the other end of the connection because these are server-side socket objects which a client can't do anything with anyway.

Comment: Since you can't send `usersInRoom` to clients, please back and up and describe what you're trying to accomplish with that code so people can suggest a different/better way to solve that problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was trying to send a list of users connected to that room to the client in order to create a `ul` element showing all the users in the room. Should I instead use a for loop to iterate over `usersInRoom` and create an array of usernames which can then be sent to the client?

Comment: When you say "list of users", exactly what is it you want to send?  `usersInRoom` contains socket objects.  That's not human readable in any way.  If you want to send a list of some identifying attribute for the user, then yes, make an array of just that identifying attribute (username, socketid, etc...) and send that array.  You can't send socket.io objects themselves over socket.io because they can't be converted to JSON and wouldn't be meaningful even if you could.

Comment: @jfriend00 `socket.username` is the value I'm trying to send. I'm not really sure why I was trying to send the whole `usersInRoom` variable in the first place. Thanks for helping clear up my confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've discussed in comments, you can't send whole socket.io connection objects over a socket.io connection as it's not something that can be converted to JSON.

If what you really want to send is just a list of `username` properties that you've attached to the socket.io object, then you can make an array of just those usernames.

Change this:

```
io.of('/game').in(roomName).emit('join', { username: socket.username, users: usersInRoom });
```

to this:

```
const usernameList = usersInRoom.map(s => s.username);
io.of('/game').in(roomName).emit('join', { username: socket.username, users:  usernameList});
```